# Remove Developer Insights from Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

[image: insights]

How I can remove this?

It's here, in the left column

[image: position]

Answer (score 1):

[F.B. Purity](http://www.fbpurity.com/) or [Social Fixer](http://socialfixer.com/) are what you looking for. I recommend using [F.B. Purity](http://www.fbpurity.com/) because it is updated more frequently.